# Hosting website at GoDaddy and using Google Apps for mail

Tags: gmail, domain-name-system, godaddy, g-suite

Got a question about hosting a website at GoDaddy and using Google Apps to handle mail for a single domain.

1) I use registrar's name servers so that I can change DNS settings.

2) I changed the A record to point to the IP address where I want to host my website and change www CNAME to `mydomain.com`

3) I changed MX records to what Google's instructions said.

The website shows up fine, but something funny is going on with e-mail. For some reason Mac mail cannot send to `user@mydomain.com`. I get:

> Verify that you have addressed this message correctly. Check your
>   SMTP server settings in Mail preferences and verify any advanced
>   settings with your system administrator.
>
> Select a different outgoing mail server from the list below or click
>   Try Later to leave the message in your Outbox until it can be sent.

When I try to send e-mail to other addresses it works fine, so I suspect something is wrong with the A record pointing one place and MX records pointing to Google.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Hmmm... this may actually belong on SuperUser.

Comment: This should work fine; I'm doing it myself on 4 different domains.  Do you have a CNAME for the naked domain?

Comment: Ah, no I don't. I have cname for www (host) CNAME mydomain.com but godaddy won't let me leave the host field blank. What do I place in there?

Comment: An A record.  CNAMEs on the naked domain break some mail servers.

Comment: I see. So in addition to @ (host) ipaddress, I also add an @ (host) mydomain.com as an A record... actually, it won't let me add a non-ip address.

Comment: Has your domain verified the MX records yet?  Sometimes it takes time for these things to propagate properly.  Having something similar (switching a domain to Google Apps) it took about 24 hours before e-mail could be properly sent from my domain owned by a different company.

Comment: The `@ (host) ip address` is what I'm talking about; it sounds like that's already good.  I don't know what the problem is.  Can you send to the domain from a Gmail or other account?

Comment: Gotcha -- thanks Slaks. I will try sending from another account. Since it's a client's address I didn't want to keep sending e-mails to it.

Comment: Shads0 -- that could be it. It's been not quite 24 hours. I'll wait several more to be sure. Thank you folks.

Comment: When working with support they told me 24-48 hours, so if it doesn't work after 24, wait one more day before panicking then call Google App support, they were very helpful when I had other issues with my domain provider.

Comment: Thank you for calling ServerFault. To better assist you, please state your domain name after the tone. *beeeeeep*  :-)  (seriously - there's not much we can do but take wild guesses without the ability to examine the DNS records ourselves)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes time for the records to propagate properly through the internet and have a valid route.  If they do not work after 24-48 hours, then you have a problem and should contact Google Apps support.